# http.jsonp coming back with cached data until manual page refresh

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My data is supposed to be the current time but I've found that when I load new data in via `$http.jsonp` that my data comes in as cached data every time. How can I change it so I get the *unchached* data back every time?

**Here's my logic test:**

```
$http.jsonp("mydataurl?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data){
  console.log(data); // always logs 0.76608400 1431562002 (only updates when I manually refresh the page)
});
```

**php**

```
<?php

echo $_GET['_jsonp'] . "(" . microtime() . ")";

?>
```

Comment: @halfer I hope you're getting paid by SOF for all your community work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append a random string at the end of the url to avoid caching.

```
$http.jsonp("mydataurl?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK&random=123").success(function(data){
  console.log(data); // always logs 0.76608400 1431562002 (only updates when I manually refresh the page)
});
```

Just make sure the random has a different value everytime. You can probably use a date on the query `"mydataurl?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK&random="+new Date()`

Comment: I added `"&u=" + (new Date).getTime()